# First divs on top

Tags: css, html, dom

I want my first relative div's on top. I want to do this in pure css. So i want the left image on top..

So say I have 3 images:
 - And I give them a CSS style
 - div.img  RELATIVE  > >  div.imga  ABSOLUTE.
 - So the RELATIVE div is the leading z-index.

I tried things like nth-child, to add z-index of new elements. But I don't know if / how its possible to be the first relative div on top.

```css
.img {
    position: relative;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.imga {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 35vw;
    background-image: url("http://executivefinance.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Big-data.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px 2px 100px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>
```

and a codepen is here: http://codepen.io/zoutepopcorn/pen/LWKYWj?editors=1100

When it's not possible, I have to stick with a Jquery :(.

```
https://codepen.io/zoutepopcorn/pen/ryEazJ

setTimeout(function() {
  var zi = $('.img:first').css('z-index') + 1 + "";
  $("#cont").prepend('<div class="img"><div class="imga"></div></div>');
  $('.img:first').css('z-index', zi);
}, 300);
```

Comment: I think the only way would be to manually set the z-index

Comment: Ai. Thanks. Maybe I have to stick with Javascript again... thanks for the comment

Comment: If you want to do it in pure CSS, AND the number of divs is not too large, then you can just do something like `.img:nth-last-child(1) {z-index:1}
.img:nth-last-child(2) {z-index:2}
.img:nth-last-child(3) {z-index:3}
.img:nth-last-child(4) {z-index:4}` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Wait. I think I understand the set-up you are trying to achieve now.

There is no need for `z-index`.

Just use `float: right`

**Example:**

```css
.img {
    position: relative;
    left: -8vw;
    float: right;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.imga {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 35vw;
    background-image: url("http://executivefinance.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Big-data.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px 2px 100px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>
<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, it didn't workout in this example
http://codepen.io/zoutepopcorn/pen/MpMJRj?editors=0110

But I learned a lot. I used some javascript in the end. But will use this trick in other projects :D

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if / how its possible to be the first relative div on
>   top.

I'm not absolutely sure that I understand your question correctly.

Do you want the relative-positioned parent element to be *visible above* the absolute-positioned child element?

If so, you can use `clip-path` to "cut out" a section of the child, revealing the relative parent element beneath - and making it look like the parent is "on top".

**Working Example:**

```css
.img {
    position: relative;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 21vw 21vw;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/150/140');
    border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.imga {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 35vw;
    background-image: url("http://executivefinance.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Big-data.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px 2px 100px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    clip-path: url("#clip-shape");
}

.img:hover .imga {
clip-path: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hover over any image</h2>

<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>

<div class="img">
<div class="imga"></div>
</div>

<svg>
<clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<polygon points="0.58 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0.58, 0.58 0.58" />
</clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nifty, clip-path is new to me. If it's new to anyone else here's some stuff you can do with it http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/